# How could I identify whether to insert or update the record with Spring jpa

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a situation in my spring project of **inventory** where I want to insert the items in the **Item** table which contains the following fields.

1. name
2. color
3. description
4. quantity
5. buying_price
6. selling_price.

Now I send a json in the request

```
{
    "name":"iphone 5s cover",
    "buyingPrice": 300,
    "color":"white",
    "description":"Hard cover for iphone",
    "sellingPrice":400,
    "quantity":30
 }
```

This thing would insert the new record in the table I am adding **Id** by `auto-increment`. 
Now when I am going to add the same item with different **quantity** it should update the quantity rather then adding a new record.

What I could do for now is to check each and everything of the request if it exists in the table it sends the **Id** or update the record at that specific Id.

Or there any other better way in the spring boot it would identify itself to update this record.
Or what I could do to handle this situation.

Tried to create a **composite key** using `@ClassId` annotation but getting the exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: property-ref [_com_was_inventory_model_Sale_items] not found on entity [com.was.inventory.model.Sale]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1078) ~[spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) ~[spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at com.was.inventory.InventoryApplication.main(InventoryApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: property-ref [_com_was_inventory_model_Sale_items] not found on entity [com.was.inventory.model.Sale]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.getReferencedProperty(PersistentClass.java:413) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl$DelayedPropertyReferenceHandlerAnnotationImpl.process(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1229) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processPropertyReferences(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1938) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1625) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:278) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370) ~[spring-orm-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359) ~[spring-orm-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: property [_com_was_inventory_model_Sale_items] not found on entity [com.was.inventory.model.Sale]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.getRecursiveProperty(PersistentClass.java:469) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.getReferencedProperty(PersistentClass.java:409) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

Here is the Entities

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Item")
@IdClass(ItemsKey.class)
public class Item implements Serializable {


   private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private Category category;

    private String description;

    private String color;

    private Long sellingPrice;

    private Long buyingPrice;

    private Integer quantity;

    private String pictureLink;

    private Set<Sale> sales;

    private Set<Orders> orders;

    private Set<Purchase> purchases;


    public Item() {
    }

    public Item(String name, Category category, String description, String color, Long sellingPrice, Long buyingPrice, Integer quantity) {
        this.name = name;
        this.category = category;
        this.description = description;
        this.color = color;
        this.sellingPrice = sellingPrice;
        this.buyingPrice = buyingPrice;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }



    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Id
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CategoryId")
    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Id
    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Long getSellingPrice() {
        return sellingPrice;
    }

    public void setSellingPrice(Long sellingPrice) {
        this.sellingPrice = sellingPrice;
    }

    public Long getBuyingPrice() {
        return buyingPrice;
    }

    public void setBuyingPrice(Long buyingPrice) {
        this.buyingPrice = buyingPrice;
    }

    public Integer getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(Integer quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public String getPictureLink() {
        return pictureLink;
    }

    public void setPictureLink(String pictureLink) {
        this.pictureLink = pictureLink;
    }

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "items")
    public Set<Sale> getSales() {
        return sales;
    }

    public void setSales(Set<Sale> sales) {
        this.sales = sales;
    }

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "ItemOrders", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Item_id",
            referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Orders_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    public Set<Orders> getOrders() {
        return orders;
    }

    public void setOrders(Set<Orders> orders) {
        this.orders = orders;
    }

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "items")
    public Set<Purchase> getPurchases() {
        return purchases;
    }

    public void setPurchases(Set<Purchase> purchases) {
        this.purchases = purchases;
    }


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return super.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return super.equals(obj);
    }
```

}

Here is the Id Class.

```
public class ItemsKey implements Serializable {

    private String name;

    private String color;

    public ItemsKey() {
    }

    public ItemsKey(String name, String color) {
        this.name = name;
        this.color = color;
    }

    /**
     * getters and setters
     **/

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name = "color", nullable = false)
    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

There are relations of this entity with some others it was working fine without adding the composite primary key.

Where I am wrong.
I want to have **id** as a primary and **name** and **color** as composite.
Does this make sense to achieve this goal.
Gratitude :)

Comment: I believe JPA will do that automatically on the save method. It behaves as a create-or-update. The important part is the ID. If you want to update, you need to also pass the correct ID into the save method with your object model.

Comment: This is the issue its auto-increment to get the id I have to get the object on the basis of color and name. is there any better way.

Comment: It sounds like you want color + name to be a unique key then?

Comment: Also thinking the same to make a composite key of them.To create an Embedable Id

Comment: yes, you need to make that your key. there is no need for you to have a auto-generated ID really if color and name already define a unique object

Answer (score -1):

You need to first fetch the `Item` by its id like so

```
Item item = itemRepository.findById(YOUR_ID);
```

Then you need to update its state like so

```
item.setQuantity(YOUR_QUANTITY);
```

And then finally update the `Item` in the database like so

```
item = itemRepository.save(item); //Now the item object contains the updated quantity.
```

Comment: I don't have the Id because I don't know whether it was inserted before or not.

Comment: There must be some key that uniquely identifies your `Item` entity!!

Comment: I have defined the composite key `color` and `name` now using the `id class` annotation but its throwing me and exception of **mapping**  like `property A_item not found in entity A`

Comment: Post your entities as well. Looks like the bug is sitting right there.

Comment: The exception log says you dont have a property `_com_was_inventory_model_Sale_items` in your `Sales` entity class!

Comment: Also, along with the composite key why are you having an additional Unique key!!

Comment: Please check [this](http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/05/01/jpa-idclass-example/) tuts on composite key. Very easy to grasp.

Comment: I want an extra key as well. and I have items in sales I don't know why its acting like that it was fine before adding the composite.